# Object is Returned null in Hibernate Select query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

i Have this following query that i am using in hibernate

```
select a.*, b.cur_date, c.value as maxloginattempts 
from tbl_user a, tbl_eod_bod_stat b, tbl_settings c 
where upper(a.id) = 'ADMIN' 
and usr_status in ('A','E','O','P','U','G','M','D','T') and c.attribute = 'MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS'";
```

my main class:-

```
  package foo;

    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
    import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

    import com.imageinfo.eclear.hbm.pojo.TblUser;

    public class myclass {
        static SessionFactory factory;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            myclass obj=new myclass();
            System.out.println("above buildfactory");
    try{
            factory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    System.out.println("after buidl");
            //obj.raiseEmailNotification();
            //obj.doAfter();
            //obj.validateInput();
            obj.checkPass();
        }
    public void checkPass(){
            String username="S5626";

            Session session =factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
            Query query=session.createQuery("select a.id,b.id,c.value as maxloginattempts from TblUser a,TblEodBodStat b,TblSettings c where upper(a.id.id)='ADMIN'  and c.attribute='MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS'");

            //query.setParameter("username", username);
            //List list=query.list();
    System.out.println("worked");
    int i=0;
    List list=query.list();

            if(!list.isEmpty()) 
            {
                for(Object a:list)
                {
                    Object[] o=(Object[])a;
                    System.out.println(o[0]);

                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(o));
                }
            }
```

when i run this the tblUser object is returned null.

**OUTPUT**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
after buidl
worked
null
[null, com.imageinfo.eclear.hbm.pojo.TblEodBodStatId@257db8ef, 3]
```

tblUser.hbm.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Dec 3, 2015 4:43:35 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.imageinfo.eclear.hbm.pojo.TblUser" table="TBL_USER">
        <composite-id name="id" class="com.imageinfo.eclear.hbm.pojo.TblUserId">
            <key-property name="id" type="string">
                <column name="ID" length="22" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="roleId" type="string">
                <column name="ROLE_ID" length="3" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="fname" type="string">
                <column name="FNAME" length="60" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="emailId" type="string">
                <column name="EMAIL_ID" length="100" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="branchCode" type="string">
                <column name="BRANCH_CODE" length="5" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="employeeCode" type="string">
                <column name="EMPLOYEE_CODE" length="20" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="departmentCode" type="string">
                <column name="DEPARTMENT_CODE" length="10" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="userCategory" type="string">
                <column name="USER_CATEGORY" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="description" type="string">
                <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="100" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="loggedStatus" type="java.lang.Byte">
                <column name="LOGGED_STATUS" precision="2" scale="0" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="lastLogged" type="timestamp">
                <column name="LAST_LOGGED" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="currentSessionId" type="string">
                <column name="CURRENT_SESSION_ID" length="34" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="currentAttempts" type="java.lang.Boolean">
                <column name="CURRENT_ATTEMPTS" precision="1" scale="0" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="expiryDate" type="date">
                <column name="EXPIRY_DATE" length="7" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="expireStatus" type="string">
                <column name="EXPIRE_STATUS" length="3" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="allowedForms" type="string">
                <column name="ALLOWED_FORMS" length="1000" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="groupId" type="string">
                <column name="GROUP_ID" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="usrActiveStatus" type="string">
                <column name="USR_ACTIVE_STATUS" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="usrStatus" type="string">
                <column name="USR_STATUS" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idmsStatus" type="string">
                <column name="IDMS_STATUS" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="creator" type="string">
                <column name="CREATOR" length="22" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="approver" type="string">
                <column name="APPROVER" length="22" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="CSessionid" type="string">
                <column name="C_SESSIONID" length="34" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="ASessionid" type="string">
                <column name="A_SESSIONID" length="34" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="creatorDate" type="timestamp">
                <column name="CREATOR_DATE" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="creatorIpAddress" type="string">
                <column name="CREATOR_IP_ADDRESS" length="15" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="approverDate" type="timestamp">
                <column name="APPROVER_DATE" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="approverIpAddress" type="string">
                <column name="APPROVER_IP_ADDRESS" length="15" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="logoutDate" type="timestamp">
                <column name="LOGOUT_DATE" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="lockedStatus" type="string">
                <column name="LOCKED_STATUS" length="1" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="userIdentity" type="string">
                <column name="USER_IDENTITY" length="20" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="passwd" type="string">
                <column name="PASSWD" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="passHist1" type="string">
                <column name="PASS_HIST1" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="passHist2" type="string">
                <column name="PASS_HIST2" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="passHist3" type="string">
                <column name="PASS_HIST3" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="passHist4" type="string">
                <column name="PASS_HIST4" length="50" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TblUserId.java**

```
package com.imageinfo.eclear.hbm.pojo;

// Generated Dec 3, 2015 4:43:34 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.4.GA

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * TblUserId generated by hbm2java
 */
public class TblUserId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String roleId;
    private String fname;
    private String emailId;
    private String branchCode;
    private String employeeCode;
    private String departmentCode;
    private String userCategory;
    private String description;
    private Byte loggedStatus;
    private Timestamp lastLogged;
    private String currentSessionId;
    private Boolean currentAttempts;
    private Date expiryDate;
    private String expireStatus;
    private String allowedForms;
    private String groupId;
    private String usrActiveStatus;
    private String usrStatus;
    private String idmsStatus;
    private String creator;
    private String approver;
    private String CSessionid;
    private String ASessionid;
    private Timestamp creatorDate;
    private String creatorIpAddress;
    private Timestamp approverDate;
    private String approverIpAddress;
    private Timestamp logoutDate;
    private String lockedStatus;
    private String userIdentity;
    private String passwd;
    private String passHist1;
    private String passHist2;
    private String passHist3;
    private String passHist4;

    public TblUserId() {
    }

    public TblUserId(String id, String roleId, String fname, String emailId,
            String branchCode, String employeeCode, String departmentCode,
            String userCategory, String description, Byte loggedStatus,
            Timestamp lastLogged, String currentSessionId,
            Boolean currentAttempts, Date expiryDate, String expireStatus,
            String allowedForms, String groupId, String usrActiveStatus,
            String usrStatus, String idmsStatus, String creator,
            String approver, String CSessionid, String ASessionid,
            Timestamp creatorDate, String creatorIpAddress,
            Timestamp approverDate, String approverIpAddress,
            Timestamp logoutDate, String lockedStatus, String userIdentity,
            String passwd, String passHist1, String passHist2,
            String passHist3, String passHist4) {
        this.id = id;
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.branchCode = branchCode;
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
        this.departmentCode = departmentCode;
        this.userCategory = userCategory;
        this.description = description;
        this.loggedStatus = loggedStatus;
        this.lastLogged = lastLogged;
        this.currentSessionId = currentSessionId;
        this.currentAttempts = currentAttempts;
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        this.expireStatus = expireStatus;
        this.allowedForms = allowedForms;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.usrActiveStatus = usrActiveStatus;
        this.usrStatus = usrStatus;
        this.idmsStatus = idmsStatus;
        this.creator = creator;
        this.approver = approver;
        this.CSessionid = CSessionid;
        this.ASessionid = ASessionid;
        this.creatorDate = creatorDate;
        this.creatorIpAddress = creatorIpAddress;
        this.approverDate = approverDate;
        this.approverIpAddress = approverIpAddress;
        this.logoutDate = logoutDate;
        this.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;
        this.userIdentity = userIdentity;
        this.passwd = passwd;
        this.passHist1 = passHist1;
        this.passHist2 = passHist2;
        this.passHist3 = passHist3;
        this.passHist4 = passHist4;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoleId() {
        return this.roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return this.fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return this.emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getBranchCode() {
        return this.branchCode;
    }

    public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
        this.branchCode = branchCode;
    }

    public String getEmployeeCode() {
        return this.employeeCode;
    }

    public void setEmployeeCode(String employeeCode) {
        this.employeeCode = employeeCode;
    }

    public String getDepartmentCode() {
        return this.departmentCode;
    }

    public void setDepartmentCode(String departmentCode) {
        this.departmentCode = departmentCode;
    }

    public String getUserCategory() {
        return this.userCategory;
    }

    public void setUserCategory(String userCategory) {
        this.userCategory = userCategory;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Byte getLoggedStatus() {
        return this.loggedStatus;
    }

    public void setLoggedStatus(Byte loggedStatus) {
        this.loggedStatus = loggedStatus;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastLogged() {
        return this.lastLogged;
    }

    public void setLastLogged(Timestamp lastLogged) {
        this.lastLogged = lastLogged;
    }

    public String getCurrentSessionId() {
        return this.currentSessionId;
    }

    public void setCurrentSessionId(String currentSessionId) {
        this.currentSessionId = currentSessionId;
    }

    public Boolean getCurrentAttempts() {
        return this.currentAttempts;
    }

    public void setCurrentAttempts(Boolean currentAttempts) {
        this.currentAttempts = currentAttempts;
    }

    public Date getExpiryDate() {
        return this.expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Date expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }

    public String getExpireStatus() {
        return this.expireStatus;
    }

    public void setExpireStatus(String expireStatus) {
        this.expireStatus = expireStatus;
    }

    public String getAllowedForms() {
        return this.allowedForms;
    }

    public void setAllowedForms(String allowedForms) {
        this.allowedForms = allowedForms;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return this.groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getUsrActiveStatus() {
        return this.usrActiveStatus;
    }

    public void setUsrActiveStatus(String usrActiveStatus) {
        this.usrActiveStatus = usrActiveStatus;
    }

    public String getUsrStatus() {
        return this.usrStatus;
    }

    public void setUsrStatus(String usrStatus) {
        this.usrStatus = usrStatus;
    }

    public String getIdmsStatus() {
        return this.idmsStatus;
    }

    public void setIdmsStatus(String idmsStatus) {
        this.idmsStatus = idmsStatus;
    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return this.creator;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public String getApprover() {
        return this.approver;
    }

    public void setApprover(String approver) {
        this.approver = approver;
    }

    public String getCSessionid() {
        return this.CSessionid;
    }

    public void setCSessionid(String CSessionid) {
        this.CSessionid = CSessionid;
    }

    public String getASessionid() {
        return this.ASessionid;
    }

    public void setASessionid(String ASessionid) {
        this.ASessionid = ASessionid;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatorDate() {
        return this.creatorDate;
    }

    public void setCreatorDate(Timestamp creatorDate) {
        this.creatorDate = creatorDate;
    }

    public String getCreatorIpAddress() {
        return this.creatorIpAddress;
    }

    public void setCreatorIpAddress(String creatorIpAddress) {
        this.creatorIpAddress = creatorIpAddress;
    }

    public Timestamp getApproverDate() {
        return this.approverDate;
    }

    public void setApproverDate(Timestamp approverDate) {
        this.approverDate = approverDate;
    }

    public String getApproverIpAddress() {
        return this.approverIpAddress;
    }

    public void setApproverIpAddress(String approverIpAddress) {
        this.approverIpAddress = approverIpAddress;
    }

    public Timestamp getLogoutDate() {
        return this.logoutDate;
    }

    public void setLogoutDate(Timestamp logoutDate) {
        this.logoutDate = logoutDate;
    }

    public String getLockedStatus() {
        return this.lockedStatus;
    }

    public void setLockedStatus(String lockedStatus) {
        this.lockedStatus = lockedStatus;
    }

    public String getUserIdentity() {
        return this.userIdentity;
    }

    public void setUserIdentity(String userIdentity) {
        this.userIdentity = userIdentity;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return this.passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }

    public String getPassHist1() {
        return this.passHist1;
    }

    public void setPassHist1(String passHist1) {
        this.passHist1 = passHist1;
    }

    public String getPassHist2() {
        return this.passHist2;
    }

    public void setPassHist2(String passHist2) {
        this.passHist2 = passHist2;
    }

    public String getPassHist3() {
        return this.passHist3;
    }

    public void setPassHist3(String passHist3) {
        this.passHist3 = passHist3;
    }

    public String getPassHist4() {
        return this.passHist4;
    }

    public void setPassHist4(String passHist4) {
        this.passHist4 = passHist4;
    }

    ));

        result = 37 * result
                + (getPasswd() == null ? 0 : this.getPasswd().hashCode());
        result = 37 * result
                + (getPassHist1() == null ? 0 : this.getPassHist1().hashCode());
        result = 37 * result
                + (getPassHist2() == null ? 0 : this.getPassHist2().hashCode());
        result = 37 * result
                + (getPassHist3() == null ? 0 : this.getPassHist3().hashCode());
        result = 37 * result
                + (getPassHist4() == null ? 0 : this.getPassHist4().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Please take note that i had several columns in tblUser of Timestamp data type.which were mapped in autogenerated hbm.xml and auto generated pojo as Serializable and because of that i was getting 'Could not deserialize Error'.later to fix that i replaced it manually with timestamp and in pojos with java.sql.Timestamp.** I am using jdk 6.
i have two doubts:-

1.what could be the possible cause for this?

2.And why does it take a lot of time ,around almost 20 seconds,to create factory object.

thank you

**P.S**

I skipped posting TblUser.java which had just one property ,an object of TbluserId class.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the query present in the java code there is one field `'a.id.id'` called. This must be the issue.

Comment: upper(a.id.id)='admin',yes that is to get details for current user and i think that shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: How are the three Tables related to each other, I don't see any relation among them in the query.Also while making the query are you getting any exception or during the call to list() method

Comment: So how are you joining them.\

Comment: Not getting any exception.

Comment: see my query ,i dont need a join

Comment: i want to select all columns from one  table and one column each from  rest

Comment: Yes and for that you need to have something in common so that you can show some relation while executing the query. The query you are using is for Inner Joins

Comment: Yes but in here The Query must be mapped with the Pojos Created, but since there are no relationships, it it not working properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96961/discussion-between-vishal-tyagi-and-vivek-singh).

Comment: i am pretty sure join is not an issue beacuse when i change in my query select a.id to a.id.id it prints out ADMIN and then required columns,but i need not just the id from tbluser but all the columns..kindly reExamine